# Text going outside container div

Tags: html, css

I am doing a school project where I am learning how to use Dreamweaver templates. I have the page built and the templates are working, but the text that is longer in the other pages is not being contained inside the Content div like it should. I am not sure why? I don't know how to make a fiddle, but this is hte code being effected.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="content" id="home_img">
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="photo" -->
     <img src="../photos-winery/napa2_edit.jpg" width="457" height="300" alt="Winery" />
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->

<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="text" -->
        <div class="text">
          <h1>A Napa Valley winery dedicated to quality wines for three generations.</h1>
          <p> Offering a selection of classic varietals to last: Merlot, Syrah, Cabernet Sauvignon, Chardonnay, Sauvignon Blanc, Chenin Blanc, and more. </p>
          <h2>Because life is too short for compromise.</h2>
          <!--end .text --></div>
      <!-- TemplateEndEditable --><!-- end .content --></div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}


.content {
    margin-top: 5em;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.28em;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 60px 0 60px;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(../photos-winery/vine_edit.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
    width: 955px;
    border: medium solid #CCC;
}


.content #home_img {
    margin: 10px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px outset #000000;
    text-align: right;
}
.text {
    width: 45%;
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 2em;
    float: right;
}
```

Any help is appreciated

[image: snippet of page]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? how it looks at your end? what needs to be different? Here is the fiddle for your code : http://jsfiddle.net/x0qf67md/

Comment: Your text is floating and the container is not floating or doing any kind of clear fix so the text floats outside. Also there is no `#container` in your html

Comment: That fiddle is what its supposed to look like. I changed the div class='container" to an ID. same result I took a snippet of it, but not sure hwo to put it in here

Comment: AH!!! floating hte content div fixed it! awesome thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HTML: `<div ID="blabla">` -->
CSS: `#blabla{}`

HTML: `<div class="blabla">` -->
CSS: `.blabla{}`

Look at the differences in your code.